# Unable to delete heroku table through django shell

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to delete a table hosted in heroku. Because it is in the shared database I can't connect to postgres directly to perform sentence. I execute delete through django shell. Issue is that table name is in uppercase and, for unknow reason, django try to delete it in lower cases:

```
>>> sql = '''drop table campings_horesEntrega cascade;    <---see uppercases
...          drop table campings_horesRecollida; '''
>>> 
>>> from django.db import connections, transaction
>>> cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
>>> cursor.execute(sql)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 40, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
DatabaseError: table "campings_horesentrega" does not exist   <--- see lowercases
```

someone has a workaround to my issue?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your table names in quotes if you want postgres to respect case.

```
DROP TABLE "campings_horesEntrega" CASCADE;
```

Comment: thanks! I'm new in postgres. I know: oracle -> ", sqlserver -> [, mysql -> `, and now postgres = oracle -> "